# Submission of form does not send me to the correct page?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm doing a form and I can't submit the form to the action. When I click the button, it doesn't send me to the action page

This is the JavaScript part:

```
        var nombre_txt = $("input[name=nombre_txt]");
        var password_txt = $("input[name=password_txt]");
        var sexo_rdo = $("input[name=sexo_rdo]");
        if (nombre_txt.val() == "") {
            alert("El campo nombre es requerido");
            nombre_txt.focus();
        }

        else if (password_txt.val() == "") {
            alert("El campo password es requerido");
            password_txt.focus();
        }
        else if ((sexo_rdo[0].checked || sexo_rdo[1].checked) == "") {
            alert("El campo sexo es requerido");
            sexo_rdo[0].focus();
        }

        if (isset($_GET["nombre_txt"]) && !empty($_GET["nombre_txt"])) {
            document.valida_datos_get_frm.submit();
```

this is the html part:

```
<form name="valida_datos_get_frm"action="validar-datos.php" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> 
Ingresa tu nombre:
<input type="text" name="nombre_txt"/> <br><br>
Ingresa tu password
<input type="password" name="password_txt"/> <br><br>
<input type="radio" name="sexo_rdo" value="M"/>
<input type="radio" name="sexo_rdo" value="F"/>
Femenino&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<br><br>
<input type="hidden" name="enviar_hdn" value="get"/>
<input type="button" name="enviar_btn" id="enviar-get" value="Enviar por GET" onclick="validarDatosGET();"/>
```

It works fine and gives me alerts when I don't complete the form, but it won't submit to the action: "validar-datos.php".

Comment: You have used PHP functions within your JavaScript code (isset/empty and also use of $_GET). Can you please submit your whole code, including the section of your JavaScript that triggers your JS validation (as the form itself has no onsubmit attribute)

Comment: It is much appreciated here if you can use descriptive titles - `Hi need some advice` would apply, presumably, to every question on Stack Overflow, and if everyone used such titles we might as well do away with them altogether. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`isset` isn't defined, so your function errors. This code...

```
isset($_GET["nombre_txt"]) && !empty($_GET["nombre_txt"])
```

...is PHP, not JavaScript. You shouldn't have it in your JavaScript click handler. I think perhaps you're looking for something more like this...

```
    if (nombre_txt.val() == "") {
        alert("El campo nombre es requerido");
        nombre_txt.focus();
    } else if (password_txt.val() == "") {
        alert("El campo password es requerido");
        password_txt.focus();
    } else if ((sexo_rdo[0].checked || sexo_rdo[1].checked) == "") {
        alert("El campo sexo es requerido");
        sexo_rdo[0].focus();
    } else {
        document.valida_datos_get_frm.submit();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, so isset its the error yes i didnt open a <?php i just opened html and <script> im trying to open a <?php at the beginign but it makes the whole code error

Comment: Yeah, that's an error. I assume you *mean* to be checking the values of the  `nombre_txt` input (like you're doing above for the password input) but you've already checked that field. So I'm confused about why the PHP string is there at all

Comment: because the code was giving me an error so i saw on forums that i could use this string , isset($_GET["nombre_txt"]) && !empty($_GET["nombre_txt"])  ,to make submit the code i forgot that isset its php only, theres some way i can make it work and submit the code without using php ? because im trying to write a code only javascript and html on the client side and php on the server side